# Mysql query select records based on given date input with out time range

Tags: mysql, date, between

I want to fetch complete data given date with out time range. Now i have a query with date range (between dates).

```
SELECT Name, age, TITLE, fee FROM students joined_on between ('2014-07-01') and ('2014-07-03') LIMIT 0,5.
```

But i want to fetch data only on single date like 2014-07-01.Because user can select
    date range or single date with out time range. For this how can i write query ?
    Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Oh, that's a tough one. Actually it's so hard, it's not worth having a try at all, right?

Comment: BTW, LIMIT without ORDER BY is a bit meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Name,Age,TITLE,fee FROM students WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2014-07-01'
```